# cp: cannot create regular file '/home/root/.ipfs': No such file or directory

Tags: ipfs

I am trying to install [Rubix Node](https://dist.rubix.network/) in Linux. I already have jdk, and I had downloaded IPFS storage zip file and proceeded as per the [instructions](https://dist.rubix.network/img/pdfs/Rubix%20Wallet%20Setup%20-%20Linux%20v1.0.pdf) and I see .ipfs file created in the root directory as well, but error comes saying there is no such .ipfs file when I am trying to run start up script file after installing ZIP file related to IPFS Network:

```
./init.sh: 2: ipfs: Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '/home/root/.ipfs': No such file or directory
./init.sh: 4: ipfs: Permission denied
./init.sh: 5: ipfs: Permission denied
./init.sh: 6: ipfs: Permission denied
./init.sh: 7: ipfs: Permission denied
./init.sh: 8: ipfs: Permission denied
./init.sh: 9: ipfs: Permission denied
```

What might be causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a permission issue. Once you are inside your Linux-SetupScript folder try:

```
chmod +x ./init.sh
```